# Can I leave a country later than I scheduled in MDAC (Malaysia Digital Arrival Card)?

Tags: malaysia, kazakh-citizens

I'm from Kazakhstan and now I'm in Malaysia as a tourist. Kazakhstani citizens have 30 days of visa-free entrance, but the only thing you need to fill in is the MDAC (Malaysia Digital Arrival Card). I wrote the leave date was 12 days after the entrance. However, I want to leave a bit later, approximately 20 days, but it is still ok in terms of 30-day visa-free entrance. However, I'm afraid the date I mentioned in the MDAC might be an issue.

Can I leave the country later than scheduled? Can I change it?

**Update:** I left not on the date that I mentioned in MDAC and nothing happened. Then, I re-entered Malaysia after some time, but they let me in without any word about it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Don't worry about it**. MDAC is a digital *arrival* card, as far as I know it's not checked at departure.  The reason it asks you how many days you're going to stay is in order to spot people on arrival who want to stay longer than their visa permits.

Context: The digital arrival card is largely a faithful replica of the [old paper arrival card](https://www.papertotravel.com/MP-227/photo/11907) it replaced.  In the old card, your length of stay was also asked, but only on the "arrival" side of the card that was collected on entry and archived at the bottom of a landfill, never to be seen again.  The "departure" side, which was the only part seen/checked by Immigration when leaving, only had your name, passport number and nationality.

Answer (score 5):

According to [the official website](https://www.imi.gov.my/index.php/faq_mdacjim/faq-malaysia-digital-arrival-card-mdac/), which doesn't have a specific answer to this in its FAQ, the only way seems to be to submit a new MDAC.

> 6. How can I correct informations [sic] that are [sic] wrongly entered?
>    You must resubmit a new MDAC form with the correct information.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. Even if I'm inside the country already?

Comment: That's the part that's unclear. In Singapore, you can amend your declaration. In Malaysia, it seems not. You might want to call/visit Imigresen.